# Why does XMVector3Transform return multiplcation by the transpose?

Tags: directx-12

I have a `XMFLOAT4X4` matrix `m`. Mathematically, I should obtain the last column of this matrix by multiplying `m` with the vector `(0, 0, 0, 1)`.

I only need the first three components of that column. For that reason, I've tried the following computation:

```
XMFLOAT3 x{};
XMStoreFloat3(&y, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&x), m));
```

I'm obviously assuming here that `XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&x), m)` is computing "`(m * (0, 0, 0, 1)).xyz`". Maybe this assumption is wrong.

Anyways, what I'm getting are the first three components of the last *row* instead. That is, I'm actually getting what I expected, but with `m` replaced by the transpose of `m`. Why is that and how can I get the right result (by a matrix-vector multiplication)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectXMath provides C++ implementations of all functions, so you can see them in the `.inl` files:

```
XMVECTOR XM_CALLCONV XMVector3Transform
(
    FXMVECTOR V,
    FXMMATRIX M
) noexcept
{
    XMVECTOR Z = XMVectorSplatZ(V);
    XMVECTOR Y = XMVectorSplatY(V);
    XMVECTOR X = XMVectorSplatX(V);

    XMVECTOR Result = XMVectorMultiplyAdd(Z, M.r[2], M.r[3]);
    Result = XMVectorMultiplyAdd(Y, M.r[1], Result);
    Result = XMVectorMultiplyAdd(X, M.r[0], Result);

    return Result;
}
```

This is a normal vector/matrix multiply assuming the implied 'w' in the vector3 is a `1`.

The result is NOT guaranteed to be a 3-vector with an implied 1. That's why there are other functions like `XMVector3TransformCoord` which divides by W and `XMVector3TransformNormal` which ignores the offset in the transformation matrix.

> Technically to transform a normal, you use the inverse of the transpose, and for pure rotation that results in the same matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, sorry, I still don't get it. It is obviously *not* a normal matrix-vector multiplication assuming an implied fourth component with value `1`. If it would be, the result would be the fourth column of the matrix, but it is the fourth *row* instead. And that means that it is the multiplication of the *transpose* of the matrix by the vector. And I wonder why that is how it is implemented and whether there is a different function which computes the actual matrix-vector multiplication. All of this clearly has nothing to do with division by the fourth coordinate.

Comment: I guess DirectX is assuming that the vectors are row vectors and the multiplication is actually a vector-matrix multiplication. Is there no function for matrix-(column-)vector multiplication?

Comment: "DirectXMath uses row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication. Handedness is determined by which function version is used (RH vs. LH), otherwise the function works with either left-handed or right-handed view coordinates."